# How can I block a site in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, blocking

I would like to block some websites to improve my productivity.

Is there any way to block some sites in Google Chrome, preferably an extension or so? It doesn't have to be "airtight" blocking (hey, it is for myself), but just deny access when I find myself accessing that page.

Note that editing my host files is *not* possible. This seems to be the only solution that comes up when googleing for it.

Comment: This answer already covers this - https://superuser.com/a/1512373/192077

Answer (score 4):

You can use an Extension like [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji). Even Adblock works fine, really.

Answer (score 2):

[K9 Web Protection](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) is a web filtering and blocking software that is *extremely* configurable.  You could turn on/off all the settings that you did/not want;filtering, word block, site block, category block,Internet time feature, content-based browsing, and more...  You can set what hours of the day you want the Internet on the computer to be blocked, and can customize each day of the week.  All settings are accessed via the web browser, and are protected by a password, which you could give to someone else and not know yourself if you wanted to completely block access.  It works cross-browsers; one configuration covers Internet Explorer, Firefox, *Chrome* and others all one the same machine.

Have used myself, with great results...highly recommend!

K9 Web Protection: http://www1.k9webprotection.com/

Did I mention that it is free?

Answer (score 0):

This question has been quite old since there is no appropriate answer here so adding one.

You can use [Requestly Chrome extension & Firefox addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa/) to block URLs matching a particular keyword, domain or any other part of URL.

Here's an example of Block/Cancel Rule to block multiple websites

1. Create a New Rule
2. Select Block/Cancel Request Rule
3. Enter the list of websites you want to block

Here's a screenshot of the rule :-

[image]