# Block websites in google chrome incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, website, google-chrome-extensions, blocking, parental-controls

I try a lot of website blocker extension for chrome, but these extension not working in incognito mode. How can I block a website completely in Google chrome?

Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of Incognito mode is to stop anything tracking your behaviour, so all extensions are disabled by design.

The solution depends on what it is you want to block. If it is such things as adult sites or social networking you may be better off switching your DNS server settings to those provided by [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/), who enable you to block various categories of sites. These settings will still be applied in Incognito mode.

If it's just one or two sites and only on a handful of computers, you could instead edit the hosts file - take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/47716/block-certain-websites-from-browser?rq=1) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wan't to block social networking sites and adult sites to. I will try these solutions.

Comment: thought they are disabled by design, you can explicitly enable Extensions, even in incognito

Comment: Thought they probably could, but I'm not a Chrome user to be honest. This solution is probably better for the OPs needs anyway as it stops workarounds by switching browsers

Answer (score 0):

A user can easily access inappropriate content by entering incognito or inprivate modes, searching for anything they want using google, yahoo, or bing, and seeing anything they want by clicking on the image tab. All the major search engines cache the image content on their servers. This incognito->search->images ultimately bypasses most parental control software and parental control routers. I've found three routers that conveniently enforce safe search at the router (I'm not affiliated with any of these in anyway. I'm just a concerned parent doing their homework.):

www.kibosh.net (enforce safe search + service)

http://www.blocksi.net/parental-control.php (enforce safe search + service or openDNS)

https://www.pcwrt.com/ (enforce safe search + openDNS)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Extensions (and other browser's addons) can be enabled in Incognito mode. You have to specifically enable this.

Let me answer this question with [Requestly - Chrome extension & Firefox addon](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa/)

You can use Requestly Block Rule to block URLs matching a particular keyword, domain or any other part of URL.

Here's an example of Block/Cancel Rule to block multiple websites

[image]

You can use the following steps to enable a Chrome Extension in Incognito mode

1. Open chrome://extensions
2. Click on Details on the extension card
3. Enable in Incognito mode by the toggle at the bottom section

Here's a blog post explaining the same - https://techmango.org/2018/09/30/how-to-enable-a-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode/