# Unable to block websites in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, blocking

I am using Internet Explorer and want to block certain websites (to increase my productivity, not that it matters). I went to: Internet Options > Privacy > Sites. It promises to block certain domains and I added three sites there:

quora.com
theverge.com
reddit.com

Yet I am able to open all three websites. What am I missing? If it helps, my Windows account is Administrator and I am using Internet Explorer 11. OS is Windows 8.1 Update 1.

Comment: By adding sites to "Per Site Privacy Actions" you've blocked the ability of those sites to store cookies on your machine, not your ability to browse to them. Blocking your access will have to be done another way.

Comment: If you were using Chrome I'd suggest looking at: http://superuser.com/questions/198753/how-can-i-block-a-site-in-chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those privacy settings control whether or not the site is able to use cookies, not whether or not you are allowed to visit them.

If you wish to block access to sites, consider using a service like the (free) OpenDNS that will allow you to control which websites will resolve to their real IP address instead of redirecting you to a "blocked" page.  http://www.opendns.com/ .

If you wish to just block the change locally, you could edit your hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc and place entries for those domains that resolve to localhost (127.0.0.1) . Be sure to make a backup of your hosts file first though!  And also be sure if you edit the file in Notepad to save as "all files", not as ".txt" or Windows will ignore the file.